# Which wording is correct, “how quick with me you are to anger” or “how quick to anger you are with me”?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

I’m trying to figure out which wording is right, or at the very least which one sounds better.

> How quick to anger you are with me.

or

> How quick with me you are to anger.

This is pretty much what’s chewing on my brain cells right now, and the correct answer would definitely provide the water bottle squirt needed to make it stop.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please make the question title match the text of the question. Also "to anger with me" doesn't sound right *at all,* which might be what's at the root of the question. Does taking off "with me" make a difference for you?

Comment: @AndrewLeach oops, will do. The setup is roughly “That isn’t the issue. It’s how quick to anger you are with me” or something along those lines. So it’s kind of important,  I just can’t hear it in any way that sounds right.

Comment: _Quick to anger_ is a meaningful phrase, but is much less meaningful if you split it up, so your second version really doesn't work.

Comment: I might suggest another variant: "How quick you are to anger with me."

Comment: 'How quick you are to get angry with me.'

Comment: I would prefer the first.  Note that it's not asking a question but rather "stating a fact".

Comment: Can you Post more detail? Some context? As they stand, neither phrase seems to work in English prose, but both could be fine in poetry.

Answer (score -1):

Neither.

> How quick you are **to anger**!

**To anger** [in the intransitive sense "to become angry"] does not take an object.

> How quick you are **to get angry**!

**get angry** *can* (but needn't) take a prepositional phrase that specifies the object of the anger:

> How quick you are to get angry *with the children*!

So there are three verbs here:

> to anger
>
> to get angry
>
> to get angry with (someone)

Comment: "To anger does not take an object." --> "The witness remained calm even though the lawyer's question was meant **to anger him**."

Comment: That's the transitive verb meaning to cause someone to become angry, to make someone angry. But the verb **anger** whose meaning is "to become angry" does not take an object.

Comment: It is the adjective **angry** that licenses the prepositional phrase. angry, short-tempered, lax, lenient, strict, patient, impatient, and so on can take a "with [someone]" phrase.

Comment: Yes, good, you've edited your answer to clarify that.